# Vim folds out of sync with syntax/incorrectly inserted

Tags: vim, folding, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have (something equivalent to) the following in a syntax file:

```
syn sync clear
syn sync fromstart
syn region fooBlock start="\<interface\>" end="\ze\<implementation\>" fold
syn region fooBlock start="\<implementation\>" end="\%$" fold
```

Syntax highlighting works just fine (as one can see by adding e.g. `matchgroup=Keyword`). Folding also basically works, but when I insert a new fold (by typing e.g. `implementation`, vim starts the fold one line later than it should. Example:

```
-  interface
|  l1
|  l2
   implementation
-  l3
|  l4
|  l5
```

When typing this, obviously I would expect the second fold to start one line earlier. Typing `zx` corrects that, as does saving and reopening the file or typing `:syn sync fromstart`.

What can I do to have vim correctly insert the folds *as I type*?

I already looked in [`:help fold-syntax`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-syntax), but as shown, `:syn sync fromstart` in the syntax file does not work.

Maybe there is a better way than using `\ze` (or the [`me=s-1`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3asyn-pattern-offset) suffix, which also yields the same result) to highlight/fold multipart regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to express the fact that the `interface` section ends *one line before an `implementation` line*. Syntax regions (and apparently especially folding) work best when there's a definite region start and region end marker (like `begin` and `end`).

I've tried to make your example work by adding `\n` to the pattern, but that also didn't work. I guess to get reliable folding, you need to switch from syntax-folding to a `'foldexpr'`, like this:

```
:setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=='interface'\|\|getline(v:lnum)=='implementation'?'>1':'='
```